# fetch the redirect object body in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, http, firefox-addon, xpcom, firefox-3

I am trying to fetch the http object content/body via registering a stream listener to channel when receiving "http-on-modify-request" notification.

`var newListener = new TracingListener(this);
subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
newListener.originalListener = subject.setNewListener(newListener);`

Thing goes well for normal object but redirect object.
I check a problem of firebug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=529536, which show that the listener will be moved to the redirected object. Consequently, OnDataAvailable will not be call for the original redirect object.

So is there a way to get the redirect object content/body through some other way?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the new Web Console in Firefox 4 is what you want to copy here.  Specifically, [take a look at this method](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/d66b9df51eff/toolkit/components/console/hudservice/HUDService.jsm#l2138).

Comment: I found that FF3.5 seems not have a good implementation about nsIHttpActivityDistributor, which block me always. OK, i think maybe i should move my focus on the FF3.6 or maybe FF4.0. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't focus on Firefox 3.5.   It won't be supported by Mozilla much longer.  I don't think 3.6 will be supported much longer after Firefox 4 too.